# git ssh to ipv6 address on non-standard port

Tags: ssh, git, ipv6

I am trying to access a git respository at a IPv6 address that has a SSH server listening on port 1111(for example).

Access is controlled by SSH key and I can open a SSH session on the gitserver using

```
ssh git@<IPv6-address> -p 1111
```

(Yes, I understand that git should not get a shell, but please disregard that)

I can access the repository using IPv4 like this :

```
git clone git@<IPv4-address>:1111/git/tarn.git
```

But the IPv6 version does not work.

```
git clone git@<IPv6-address>:1111/git/tarn.git
 Cloning into 'tarn'...
ssh: connect to host <IPv6 address> port 22: No route to host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

What do I need here?

Comment: IPv6 address literals usually go in square brackets to distinguish their colon from the IP-vs-port colon: `git clone 'foo@[::1]:4711/this/that.git'`, but I don't have a setup here to verify. Remember the shell may have ideas about what `[]` means if you don't quote it.

Comment: Is the IPv6 address a link-local address (beginning with `FE80`) or a globally routable address (beginning with `2`)? Can you ping the address?

Comment: @JohanMyréen This is not a fe80 addresss. `scope global dynamic noprefixroute`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Ah! That's the answer.

Comment: OpenSSH rejected the brackets feature request for ssh (even though `scp` supports it) https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1602

Answer (score 1):

You can put the SSH port in you local SSH client configuration file, then you won't have to specify it with a connection attempt (either with *ssh* directly or through *git*).

Just create a file `~/.ssh/config` and add:

```
Host <IPv6-address>
    Port 1111
```